# How to Change Multiple Color Objects indipendently with a single color picker in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, switch-statement, color-picker

I'm facing an interface problem and being a beginner I wouldn't know how to handle it. I'll explain briefly.I have a Brain object with all its parts as children objects (thalamus, arteries..) and for each of these objects I have a button that shows/hides it and a button (Color) that when pressed brings out a colour wheel connected to it so that the user can choose to change the colour of a given object (not all together but independently). The problem is the following: how to make it so that when the colour button is pressed the colour wheel is shown (which already works) but that it only acts for a certain object (the one related to the colour button) without having to create n different wheels for n objects.

I did a script that works on only one single object but can't work if it is assigned on different objects; creating a Vector of materials BodyColorMat, like this

```
   //render blue color
    public void BlueColor()
    {
        renderer.material = BodyColorMat[0];
        CurrMat = renderer.material;
    }
```

I should change method?

Comment: You're going to have to show more code, there's not enough context in the code snippet to properly help you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how many objects you have, use the mesh renderer array.

```cs
[SerializeField] private MeshRenderer[] meshRenderers;

public void SetColor(Color color)
{
    foreach (var meshRenderer in meshRenderers)
    {
        meshRenderer.material.color = color;
    }
}
```

---

### Test Example

```cs
public Color _color;
private void OnValidate() => SetColor(_color);
```

[image: Color Picker]

Answer (score 0):

It's a pure architectural problem: you need to delegate the functionality to proper classes and set up communication between them:

- colorable object should be able to fire OnSelect event and pass itself to it,
- selection manager should catch this event and deconstruct what has come to its interfaces and fire an event per each significant interface that you wish to use for communications
- color wheel manager is subscribed to selection manager's OnColorableSelected event where it will get BrainPart as IColorable and would be able to set its color.

  ```
  interface IColorable {
    Color CurrentColor {get; set;}
  }

  class BrainPart : MonoBehaviour, IColorable {
    public Color CurrentColor {
        get => _currentColor;
        set => _currentColor = AssignColorTomaterialInstance(value);
    }

    // Fire this event when user selects this object, pass `this` to `Invoke()` method
    public UnityEvent<BrainPart> OnSelected; 
    // Here you change material instance color
    AssignColorToMaterialInstance(Color color) => ... 
  }

  class ColorWheelController : MonoBehaviour {
    void ShowColorWheel(IColorable colorable) => ...
  }

  class SelectionManager: MonoBehaviour {
    public UnityEvent<IColorable> OnColorableObjectSelected;
    void BrainPartSelected(BrainPart brainPart) {
        OnColorableObjectSelected.Invoke(brainPart);
    }
  }
  ```